# Unable to ping my composer business network. I have all my docker containers running properly but the error says - "No peers available to query"

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am working on a hyperledger composer project and everything worked fine till yesterday. But today when I retried all the commands step by step :

1) start Fabric

2) create peer admin card

3) I already had my .bna file

4) installing the network into the peers

5) start the network

6) import the networkadmin card

7) ping the business network :

```
composer network ping --card admin@tutorial-network
```

Now, when I am trying to ping the network at step 7,firstly it takes a lot of time and then it throws an error:

```
Error: Error trying to ping. Error: No peers available to query. last 
error was Error: Failed to connect before the deadline
Command failed
```

I checked the running docker conatiners and it had everything up and running.

What might be the mistake ?

Comment: Instead of importing the card, I was using the previous card and that was causing the trouble. Deleting the old one and creating a new one solved the issue. But still not sure why was it a problem!

Comment: Most probably because of an outdated connection profile in the old card...